# Unable to perform $merge aggregation in cron job in nodejs+mongodb

Tags: mongodb, cron, aggregation-framework, cron-task, node-cron

I tried to create a `cron` job that gets data from one collection and do some operations using aggregate method and finally dump the output to another collection in same database (using `$merge`). If I try the code for aggregate in mongo shell, then the `$merge` happens successfully. But when it is done in a cron job, I could see that the aggregation is being performed, but the result is not getting dumped to the destined collection (which is supposed to be done by `$merge`).

Here is the code I tried to implement

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const job = new CronJob( '* * * * *', () => {
     console.log('Cron Job started');
     dbColl.aggregate([
       -----------------
       some calculations
       -----------------
       { $merge: { into: { db: 'db-name', coll: 'collection-name' } } }
     ], (err, docs) => {
          if(!err && docs){
             console.log('Cron Job ended');
             console.log(docs);  //I'm getting the correct output for the docs
          }
     })
})
```

Result

```
Cron Job started
Cron Job ended
{
   ---docs---
}
```

Note: There is no issue with aggregate function as I have tested it in mongo shell. The issue happens when the aggregate function is performed in a cron job

Answer (score 0):

The merge option didn't work. But I used callback function of aggregated method and updated the result in that

```
dbColl.aggregate([
       -----------------
       some calculations
       -----------------
       { $merge: { into: { db: 'db-name', coll: 'collection-name' } } }
     ], (err, docs) => {
          if(!err && docs){
             db.collection.updateMany(docs);
          }
     })
```